# PHP hostname query WITHOUT DNS

Tags: php, hostname

Is there a way to query a host for its name directly instead of calling on DNS?

I am aware of gethostbyaddr(), but I much rather be able to ask a host directly for its name - for as long as it knows it has one.

Comment: What kind of services (reachable via network/internet) can you expect these hosts to run?

Comment: Excellent question.. It could be anything or nothing. There are Windows computers responding to NETBIOS. Others may respond to HTTP, SNMP. If they don't respond, that's when I'd resort to DNS.

Comment: You use gethostbyname() to query for an IP address, so you can establish a connection.  It's configurable at the OS level whether gethostbyname() uses DNS, a static hosts file, or "something else" (remember"yellow pages"?).  You *DON'T* need to call "gethostbyname()" if you already have the IP address.  Or if you want to broadcast.  You *DO* need an IP address to communicate with a host (or hosts) over a socket in the first place.

Comment: Aye. I'm essentially just making a little script to loop through a full subnet of IP addresses to check if the hosts are dead or alive. If alive, I like to know a little bit more about them - such as their given names. Very often, these names don't register in DNS, so I am looking for a way to ask them for their own identities. (It could be "Batmans iphone")